# Is it able to compile HTML for a slot?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to pass rendered HTML code to a slot and I don't know how to achieve that.
I was thinking of doing something like this:
(parent component):

```html
<app-alert  :show="alert.showAlert"
                    :typeOfAlert="alert.type"
                    :width="'50%'"
                    @onCloseAlert="closeAlert">
            <template v-slot:title>
                {{ alert.title }}
            </template>
            <template v-slot:message v-html="alert.message">
             <!-- I want this to compile a String into HTML -->
            </template>
</app-alert>
```

And this is how the child template looks like:

```html
<template>
    <div class="alert py-4">
        <div class="container" :style="{'width': width}">
            <div class="notification" v-if="show" :class="typeOfAlert">
                <button class="delete" @click="onCloseAlert"></button>
                <header>
                    <h1 class="title is-4 mb-0">
                        <slot name="title"></slot>
                    </h1>
                </header>
                <p>
                    <slot name="message"></slot>
                </p>
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: does `message` property contain a raw html like `<p>some text</p>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-html` only works on DOM elements. I assume `alert.message` only contains inline elements (otherwise it should not be inside a `<p>`). Try something like this:

```html
<template v-slot:message>
  <span v-html="alert.message"></span>
</template>
```

`v-html` should be avoided as much as possible because it allows XSS attacks. `alert.message` should not contain user-generated content.

Comment: Thank you, now It works. In this case the `alert.message` just contains inline elements like you mention and the data is trusted since I'm who uses this component only.